# Wordpress AJAX How to Implement Server Side Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm attempting to implement an AJAX request and response all within one wordpress page.  My request is getting a response containing the page's html contents, and not the data that my response function is supposed to output.  Do I need to enqueue the response script from a separate file?

```
b.on("click", function(){

var data = []
data = retrieve_hst()
console.log(data)

jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: { action: "recordData", hst_data: data }
}).done(function(response) {
  alert (response);
});

<?php

  add_action('wp_ajax_recordData', 'recordData' );
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wps_recordData', 'recordData' );
  function recordData() {

    $data = $_POST['hst_data'];
    echo $data;
    die();
  }
?>
})
```

Comment: Where is that PHP code located? It should go in your functions file, or some file that gets included on all pages, before any output at all.

Comment: I have this code written directly into one of my pages.  I tried placing the server side php script into functions.php but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Your `add_action` hooks should be placed inside your theme's `functions.php` file (or in a standalone plugin).

Comment: The ajax request isn't actually calling your page, it's calling `./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. I would also recommend removing the initial `.` from the path. It should work from the functions.php-file. If it doesn't then there's something else wrong (which we can't see here).

Comment: Thank you Magnus and Hector.  I removed the initial dot from the path and put the action hooks into the functions.php file and it's working now.  That was helpful, most of the tutorials I found online don't mention placing those in functions.php.